# Grep issue with if else statement in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to check whether a docker container exists using grep.

The following script signals an error exit during running when `IMAGE` is empty and is fine when `IMAGE` is set. I can't find out the cause.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

IMAGE=$(docker ps | grep my-dev-image)

if [[ -z "$IMAGE" ]]; then
  echo "It is not there"
else
  echo "It is there"
fi
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Relevant: [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) - *Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?* -- if in a hurry, be sure to read the exercises section.

Comment: The script generates an error exit and stops because of `set -e`.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `set -e` in a script the shell will exit whenever a command fails. It interacts badly with your `grep` call because `grep` exits with an error code if it doesn't find a match. If `grep` fails then the entire `IMAGE=$(...)` assignment fails and the script exits instead of setting `IMAGE` to an empty string.

You can fix this by ensuring the assignment always succeeds. A common idiom for this is to append `|| :`. Adding `|| cmd` will run `cmd` whenever the command on the left fails. And `:` is a command that always succeeds. (Yes, it's a command name consisting of a single colon. Strange, but it's a legal identifier.)

```
IMAGE=$(docker ps | grep my-dev-image) || :
```

Alternatively, you could check `grep`'s exit code directly by using it in the `if` statement. This is what I would do if I didn't care about `grep`'s output:

```
if docker ps | grep -q my-dev-image; then
    echo "It is there"
else
    echo "It is not there"
fi
```